# MQTT: Unable to connect to the remote server

Tags: c#, websocket, mqtt

I am working on an instant messaging feature using MQTT.

I am new to this I dont have much knowledge about this please guide me if I am wrong.

When I am sending the message in MQTT it is returning me an error.
and error is:

```
{MQTTnet.Exceptions.MqttCommunicationException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: A security error occurred
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WinHttpWebSocket.<ConnectAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHandle.<ConnectAsyncCore>d__20.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHandle.<ConnectAsyncCore>d__20.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.ClientWebSocket.<ConnectAsyncCore>d__16.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MQTTnet.Implementations.MqttWebSocketChannel.<ConnectAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MQTTnet.Internal.TaskExtensions.<TimeoutAfterAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MQTTnet.Adapter.MqttChannelAdapter.<ConnectAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MQTTnet.Adapter.MqttChannelAdapter.WrapException(Exception exception)
   at MQTTnet.Adapter.MqttChannelAdapter.<ConnectAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MQTTnet.Client.MqttClient.<ConnectAsync>d__30.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at MQTTnet.Client.MqttClient.<ConnectAsync>d__30.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at VCL_Communications.MQTTClient.<ConnectClient>d__32.MoveNext() in C:\Users\oms\source\Workspaces\Workspace\VolunteerSuite\H2-branch\VCL_CommunicationsSTD\MQTT\MQTTClient.cs:line 280}
```

and the function where is occurring is:

```
private async Task ConnectClient()
        {
            
            try
            {
                stopFlag = false; //reset the stop flag
                Guid theGuid = Guid.NewGuid();// new Guid();

                // Use WebSocket connection.
                var options = new MqttClientOptionsBuilder()
                        .WithWebSocketServer(SERVER_URL)
                        .WithCredentials(SERVER_USER, SERVER_PW)
                        .WithClientId(TOPIC_SERVER_PREFIX + "|" + SYSTEM_TYPE + "|" + senderProfileId.ToString() + "|" + theGuid.ToString().Substring(0, 10))
                        .WithCleanSession(true)
                        .Build();

                //add tls if app
                if (_isApp)
                {
                    
                    options.ChannelOptions.TlsOptions.UseTls = true;
                    options.ChannelOptions.TlsOptions.SslProtocol = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12;
                }

                // **Here it is failing, returning error**
                await client.ConnectAsync(options);
                if (verbose)
                {
                    WriteLog("MQTT c: Connected to MQTT Server");
                }
            }catch (Exception ex)
            {
                WriteLog("MQTT c: Error connecting: " + ex.Message);
            }
           
        }
```

All credentials are correct and it is reacting to the server as well I can see through the broker's Dashboard

**Here it is failing, returning error**

`await client.ConnectAsync(options);`

Comment: The exception implies a certificate issue. You’ll need to follow the instructions for the broker on how to configure the correct certificates (or not use TLS).

Comment: Also WebSockets over TLS is likely to be inferred from the URL schema